# Javascript not executed when loading output of XSLTProcessor::transformToDocument() in an Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

I'm loading the output (HTMLDocument) of XSLTProcessor::transformToDocument()  into an Iframe.

The HTML is properly rendered, but the Javascripts present in the output are not executed / triggered (below is the FF inspector output)

```
<iframe id="output-frame"></iframe>
#document
<html> 
   <head></head>    
   <body onload="console.log('hello')">Hello</body>
</html>
```

If I reference a static html file instead, it is working fine :

```
<iframe id="output-frame" src="iframe.html"></iframe>
#document
<html> 
   <head></head>    
   <body onload="console.log('hello')">Hello</body>
</html>
```

Is there a technique to explicitly trigger the inner javascript ?

The issue comes maybe from the [technique I'm using](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createHTMLDocument) to load the HTMLDocument into the Iframe :

```
var doc = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xml);
var frame = document.getElementById("output-frame");
var destDocument = frame.contentDocument;
var srcNode = doc.documentElement;
var newNode = destDocument.importNode(srcNode, true);
destDocument.replaceChild(newNode, destDocument.documentElement);
```

I don't really need to use an Iframe, I'm ok to replace the current page with the result of transformToDocument().

I'm testing in FF62.

[update] I have found [External JavaScript doesn't work in iFrames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414461/external-javascript-doesnt-work-in-iframes) which looks related.

I have tried to specify a same origin src on the iframe (that will be overridden later by my transformation output) but it does not help.

Does someone know how to log "Same-origin" violation/conflict in FF ?

Comment: There is the old DOM Level 0 way of doing `destDocument.open(); destDocument.write(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(doc)); destDocument.close();`.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/semantics-scripting.html#interaction-of-script-elements-and-xslt suggests you might have more success having script elements being created by XSLTProcessor executed on insertion in a document if you use `transformToFragment`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MartinHonnen - your first option is working fine and I could actually replace the parent page with it and get rid of my frame.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that allows you to set the source of your iframe to any object you want (including HTML documents created by `XSLTProcessor::transformToDocument()`).

1. create a `Blob` object and pass it to `URL.createObjectURL(blob)`
2. set your iframe src to the returned url

The browser will fetch the specified resource and handle it like any other. For HTML documents this means that included `<script>` or `<style>` elements will be evaluated just as you would expect it.

For your concrete usecase it would look like this:

```js
let xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);

let htmlDoc = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xml);
let htmlDocStr = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(htmlDoc);

const getBlobURL = (code, type) => {
    const blob = new Blob([code], { type })
    return URL.createObjectURL(blob)
}

document.getElementById("my-iframe").src = getBlobURL(htmlDocStr, 'text/html');
```

Have a look at [this blog post](https://dev.to/pulljosh/how-to-load-html-css-and-js-code-into-an-iframe-2blc) for some background information.